# Trying to Order DB Column Alphabetically using CASE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `database table` that contains a number of fields that have a value of `NULL` for a specific `column` called category.

Currently I am executing this `statement` that returns a list of all the entries with `NULL` appearing at the end. However, for some reason it is not sorting them alphabetically and I'm wondering If someone can help me?

This is my script:

```
SELECT c.* FROM `directorycolumn` c
WHERE `c`.`directorycompany_id` = 740
ORDER BY CASE WHEN `category` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC
```

This outputs The category `column` with `NULL` values at the end but not in alphabetical order. I.e The first entry category begins with a T...but I have categories beginning with A.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a second `Order By` clause:

```
SELECT c.* FROM `directorycolumn` c
WHERE `c`.`directorycompany_id` = 740
ORDER BY CASE WHEN `category` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC, `category` ASC
```